# Taking php class inside session variable across pages gives __PHP_Incomplete_Class

Tags: php

---

I have a simple PHP class

```
 class User
 {
public IsAuthenticated;
    public Name;
    public Mail;
}
```

---

on index.php I have a form for login

```
            <form method="post" action="index2.php" >

                <p>

                    Enter your username:
                    <input type="text" name="user">

                </p>

                <p>
                    Enter your password:
                    <input type="password" name="pass">

                </p>

                <p>

                    <input 
                        type="submit" 
                        name="Submit"
                        value="Submit">

                </p>

            </form>
```

---

on index2.php I check user and password and save the data on an instance of the class, and save that class on a session["us"] variable.

```
                include("domain/userClass.php");

                session_start();

                if (($_POST["user"] == "rui") and
                    ($_POST["pass"] == "rui")) {

                    $user = new User();
                    $user->IsAuthenticated = true;
                    $user->userName = $_POST["user"];
                    $user->userPass = $_POST["pass"];

                    $_SESSION["session"] = serialize($user);

                }
```

so far so good.

---

now I navigate to index3.php

I run this script

```
include("domain/userClass.php");

session_start();


    $user = unserialize($_SESSION["session"]);

    echo "<br>" . get_class($user);

    echo "<br>is autenthicated ? " . $user->IsAuthenticated;
```

---

and I get

__PHP_Incomplete_Class

is autenthicated ?

any ideas?

thanks
Rui

Comment: That is not a PHP class. [Learn how to create classes](http://php.net/classes). Also, turn on [error reporting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6090500/how-to-get-a-detailed-error-report-when-a-php-mysql-script-fails).

Comment: very helpfull thanks, I fixed the sintax here.....


problem stil presists

Comment: got some errors in the log that might help, thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Mr.  Sverri M. Olsen

Your hint gave the way to solve this. After logging has suggested, turns out that PHP has some difficulty with relative paths.

My class was sitting on a different folder structure there fore the include was not being processed with the error message, file not found.

After fixing the relative path everything is working perfectly.

Thanks again
Rui